# I failed with deserialize my arraylist object in java socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist, deserialization

I'm writing my game in Java. It is a multiplayer game and whole communication is going trough server. Each client <-> server socket link works in separate Threat.

Server class holds clients in this array:

```
public ClientServerThread clients[];
```

I also store rooms that holds players and game objects

```
public ArrayList<GameRoom> channels;
```

I create a game on server and send whole game object co 2 clients (host and guest) like this:

```
                Message carry on info about players and their choices about army.
                     */
                msgOut = new Message(Message.START_GAME, "SERVER", Message.OK, "ROOM: " + gameRoom.getName());
                /*
                Creating a game
                 */
                ArrayList<Player> players = gameRoom.getPlayers();
                //Assiging players
                //Creating game - generate map, deal cards - setup army etc.
                Game game = new Game(players);
                //setting game in gameRoom on server.
                gameRoom.setGame(game);
                //Setting msg to carry whole game
                msgOut.setGame(game);
                //Sending response to both clients in room;
                server.announceInRoom(gameRoom, msgOut);
```

I double check on debug - game object looks fine.
Both host and guest should get game object with whole array lists in it which in this case will be army of Units.

Console debug (look at army size) :

```
server.send() {type='START_GAME', sender='SERVER', content='OK', recipient='ROOM: dddGame:Host Player:adads,Nation:1,**Army size:8** Guest Player:dcfvv,Nation:7,**Army size:8** Map: manouvre.game.Map@6a84cb2a'} PortID: 53780
server.send() {type='START_GAME', sender='SERVER', content='OK', recipient='ROOM: dddGame:Host Player:adads,Nation:1,Army size:8 Guest Player:dcfvv,Nation:7,Army size:8 Map: manouvre.game.Map@6a84cb2a'} PortID: 53781
```

On client side i have message handler :

```
               case Message.START_GAME:
                  if(msg.getContentP() == Message.OK)
                  {

                    Game game = msg.getGame();

                    /* Create and display the form */
                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                if(currentPlayer.isHost() )
                                { 
                                    clientGame = new GameWindow( game , SocketClient.this,  CreateRoomWindow.AS_HOST );
                                }
                                else 
                                { 
                                    clientGame = new GameWindow( game, SocketClient.this,  CreateRoomWindow.AS_GUEST );
                                }

                                clientGame.setVisible(true);
                                roomWindow.setVisible(false);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(GameWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                     });
                  }
                  break;
```

Problem is that after deserialization  i dont get whole game object, 
Host client is missing ArrayList hostarmy and ArrayList guestArmy

Console debug: (look at army size)

```
Outgoing : {type='START_GAME', sender='adads', content='Start Game', recipient='SERVER'}
Incoming : {type='START_GAME', sender='SERVER', content='OK', recipient='ROOM: dddGame:Host Player:adads,Nation:1,**Army size:0** Guest Player:dcfvv,Nation:7,**Army size:0** Map: manouvre.game.Map@74dc7796'}
```

strangely guest client gets  ArrayList guestArmy but no host army :/

```
Incoming : {type='START_GAME', sender='SERVER', content='OK', recipient='ROOM: dddGame:Host Player:adads,Nation:1,**Army size:0** Guest Player:dcfvv,Nation:7,**Army size:8** Map: manouvre.game.Map@700deeaf'}
```

I set serialVersionUID of every class involved. Im running out of ideas

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post your class `Message` and also show how did you send them through socket?

Comment: can you post your `Game` class?

Comment: Let's not go through a ton of code, most of it not relevant to your problem, and instead it would be best to simplify the problem and create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: @MGordon    Whole project is hosted on GIT: Game: [link](https://github.com/zimoch84/Manouvre/blob/master/src/manouvre/game/Game.java) ,  Message: [link](https://github.com/zimoch84/Manouvre/blob/master/src/manouvre/network/client/Message.java)

Comment: @HaifengZhang  Message: [link](https://github.com/zimoch84/Manouvre/blob/master/src/manouvre/network/client/Message.java)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, its the last thing i 'm gonna do - but maybe someone points me error sooner - I.m not an expert in Java field and probably I did some core error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was something with threads and accessing/referencing to memory allocation.

I studied this article: [Java concurency](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html)

and synchronized keyword didnt help me a lot.

I digged deeper and decided to try to clone game object before sending to clients. I've red that article: [Java deep copies techniques](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/) and decided to use UnoptimizedDeepCopy since it operates on synchronized functions - and it worked.

Now my code looks like this

> ```
>                 Game game = new Game(players2);
>                 Game game2 = (Game) UnoptimizedDeepCopy.copy (game);
>                 msgOut.setGame(game2);
> ```